# OpenGL concept question

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I'm just starting OpenGL programming in Win32 C++ so don't be too hard on me :) I've been wandering along the NeHe tutorials and 'the red book' a bit now, but I'm confused. So far I've been able to set up an OpenGL window, draw some triangles etc, no problem. But now I want to build a model and view it from different angles. So do we:

1. Load a model into memory (saving triangles/quads coordinates in structs on the heap) and in each scene render we draw all stuff we have to the screen using `glVertex3f` and so on.
2. Load/draw the model once using `glVertex3f` etc and we can just change the viewing position in each scene.
3. Other...?

It seems to me option 1 is most plausible from all I read so far, however it seems a bit ehh.. dumb! Do we have to decide which objects are visible, and only draw those. Isn't that very slow? Option 2 might seem more attractive :)

EDIT: Thanks for all the help, I've decided to do: read my model from file, then load it into the GPU memory using `glBufferData` and then feed that data to the render function using `glVertexPointer` and `glDrawArrays`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to understand, that OpenGL actually doesn't understand the term *"model"*, all what OpenGL sees is a stream of vertices coming in and depending on the current mode it uses those streams of vertices to draw triangles to the screen.

Every frame drawing iteration follows some outline like this:

- clear all buffers
- for each window element (main scene, HUD, minimap, etc.):

  - set scissor and viewport
  - conditionally clear depth and/or stencil
  - set projection matrix
  - set modelview matrix for initial view
  - for each model

    - apply model transformation onto matrix stack
    - bind model data (textures, vertices, etc.)
    - issue model drawing commands
- swap buffers

OpenGL does not remember what's happening up there. There was (is) some facility, called *Display Lists* but they are not able to store all kinds of commands – also they got deprecated and removed from recent OpenGL versions. The immediate mode commands *glBegin, glEnd, glVertex, glNormal and glTexCoord* have been removed as well.

So the idea is to upload some data (textures, vertex arrays, etc.) into OpenGL buffer objects. However only textures are directly understood by OpenGL as what they are (images). All other kinds of buffers require you telling OpenGL how to deal with them. This is done by calls to  *gl{Vertex,Color,TexCoord,Normal,Attrib}Pointer* to set data access parameters and *glDraw{Arrays,Elements}* to trigger OpenGL fetching a stream of vertices to be fed to the rasterizer.

Comment: Aaah ok, so the whole idea changed a bit over the years. Old tutorials still use those immediate mode commands. I think I'll have look in the local bookstore for a recent one, all this is getting very complicated (and I considered myself king after I mastered the windows GDI...)

Comment: @the_source: The basic idea never changed, but what got streamlined is the way, data is sent to OpenGL. On recent OpenGL implementations a glBegin … glEnd block is in-situ turned into a vertex array, but below the OpenGL level (means that you don't magically get a usable VA from immediate mode calls). Every call to glVertex is like pushing the next vertex attribute vector to the end of the vertex array, expanding it on the go.

Comment: @the_source Quite unrelated comment, but as you are talking about books. If you are really looking for a book about modern GL without deprecated functionality, I would recommend the NEWEST edition of the SuperBible, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926357/c-opengl-books) for more info. The Red Book is definitely a bit outdated. But as datenwolf said, it doesn't do any harm to learn OpenGL from the old style, as the underlying concepts won't change that much.

Comment: Thanks Christian, and that is a very helpful link!

Answer (score 4):

You should upload the data to the GPU memory once, and then draw each frame using as few commands as possible.

Previously, this was done using display lists. Nowadays, it's all about vertex buffer objects (a.k.a. VBOs), so look into those.

Here's [a tutorial](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html) about VBOs, written before they were only an extension, and not a core part of OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks, so it is actually option 1, but instead of on the heap we store the model in GPU memory? And we still have to draw everything each frame?

Comment: @the_source: Sort of. You won't be specifying each vertex (which was my main point), but you need to draw the scene each frame still. It's just waaay faster to tell the GPU to render data it already has on local memory, than having the CPU send _each vertex_ one at a time _each frame_.

Comment: Indeed yes, you don't have to send the data to the GPU each frame, but you do have to render it :)